# How do I mock invocations to methods in super class using jMockit

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmockit

I have a scenario in which I have to mock a method in parent class. The method is invoked from the method under test. I have not been able to mock the function using jMockit.

My super class is method is as follows

```
public abstract class SuperClass {

    protected void emailRecipients(List<String> recipients) {
       // Email recipients code. I want to mock this function.
    }
}
```

My subclass is as follows

```
public class MyClass extends SuperClass {
   public void methodUnderTest(HttpServletRequest request) {

    // Some code here.
    List<String> recipients = new ArrayList<>();
    recipients.add("foo@example.com");
    recipients.add("bar@example.com");

    // This needs to be mocked.
    this.emailRecipients(recipients);
  }
}
```

I have tried using [partial mocks using jMockit's tutorial](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Mocking.html#partial), but it has not worked for me. My test method is given below.

**UPDATE**: I implemented Rogerio's suggestion as follows. The implementation still calls the real method. When I debug the instance of mocked class in Eclipse, this is what I see `com.project.web.mvc.$Subclass_superClass@6b38c54e`

```
@Test
public void testMethodUnderTest(@Mocked final SuperClass superClass) throws Exception {
     final MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
     new Expectations(myClass) {{
         // .. Other expectations here
         superClass.emailRecipients((List<String>) any);
     }};
     MockHttpServletRequest req = new MockHttpServletRequest();
     myClass.methodUnderTest(req);
}
```

The issue is that when I try to mock the invocation of `emailRecipients`, it always tries to call the actual function. I am using Java 7, jMockit v1.35, and Maven 3x for our builds.

**UPDATE** The code is legacy code. As a result, we can't update it. We can not use PowerMock as it is not among the libraries that have been approved by the company. We can use either jMockit or Mockito or a combination of both.

Comment: If you need to mock `SuperClass`, then declare it to be `@Mocked`. It's as simple as that.

Comment: If this legacy code is not ment to be changed at all in future, what do you need the unit tests for?

Comment: I am writing tests for the functionality.

Comment: @Rogerio I need to mock the function in the superclass, not the super class itself.

Comment: Is jMockit really your only choice? In Mockito you could do myClass = spy(myClass), which is a mock based on object that refers to real method by default allowing you to only mock a few methods (from superclass for example) when needed. I don't see any such functionality at first glance on jMockit page (but I never used it, so it might hide somewhere).

Comment: Exactly! To mock the "function in the superclass", you mock the superclass. Try it!

Comment: @Rogério, how do I do that? I have seen this approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654422/jmockit-mock-protected-method-in-superclass-and-still-test-method-in-real-child, but it did not work for me. I also tried MockUp<..> implementation, but that did not work for me either. Any code samples would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: @Deltharis I have some static methods in the function under test. Mockito can not mock those. I have to use jMockit.

Comment: As I mentioned in my initial comment, declare a `@Mocked SuperClass mock` field/parameter; then the test can record/verify expectations on the mocked super-class methods.

Comment: @Rogério so I have to write something like this in the expecations block, `mock.emailRecipients(List<String> any)`, it will work?

Comment: Yes, should work.

Comment: This does not work for me. Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

see below example

P.S. use Mockito.any(HttpServletRequest.class)instead of Mockito.any(ArrayList.class) for your code

Super Class

```
public abstract class SuperClass {

    protected void emailRecipients(List<String> recipients) {
       System.out.println("Emailed!");
    }
}
```

MyClass

```
public class MyClass extends SuperClass {
    public void methodUnderTest() {

        // Some code here.
        ArrayList<String> recipients = new ArrayList<>();
        recipients.add("foo@example.com");
        recipients.add("bar@example.com");

        // This needs to be mocked.
        this.emailRecipients(recipients);
    }
}
```

Test Class

```
public class TestCase {

    MyClass myClass = Mockito.mock(MyClass.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);

    @Before
    public void prepare() {

        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(myClass).emailRecipients(Mockito.any(ArrayList.class));

        /*PowerMockito.doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {

        @Override
        public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("Custom code");
            return null;
        }
        }).when(myClass).emailRecipients(Mockito.any(ArrayList.class));*/
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethodUnderTest() throws Exception {

        myClass.methodUnderTest();
    }
}
```

If you don't want the code in emailRecipients to execute then use doNothing()
else use doAnswer to execute some other code

Comment: We can't use PowerMock. It is not among the third party libraries that have been cleared by the company. We can only use jMockit.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you want to mock the method from parent class shows that your approach fails the *Separation of Concerns/Single responsibility Pattern* (SoC/SRP).

The use of *PowerMock* as suggested by Rajiv Kapoor is possible but this (as any use of *PowerMock*) would be a surrender to bad design.

You can solve your design problem by applying the *Favor Composition over Inheritance* principle (FCoI).

To do so you'd change your (most likely) abstract super class into a "normal" class. You'd create an *interface* that declares all the `public` and `abstract` methods in your super class. Your child class would no longer extend the parent class but  implement the interface. It would get an instance of the former parent class as *dependency* and call it's methods providing common behavior as needed.

This dependency can easily mocked without the need of <strike>PowerMock</strike>.

---

> UPDATE The code is legacy code. As a result, we can't update it.

In that case you are outruled.

The code you have is not *unittestable* because it is written in an untestable way. Your only chance is to write *module* and/or *acceptance* tests (without the use of a mocking framework) covering each and every execution path through your code.

This test will be expensive to create and slow but they will gurad your when refactoring the code to something testable (== changable) later.

Comment: The code is a legacy code. It can't be refactored without breaking a lot of use cases. The code can't be change.d

Comment: In that case refactoring might be to dangerous. But using *PowerMock* will effectively vanish any chance to improve the code later. This is because the "PowerMock Tests" will break on refactoring and therefore not guard your preserving the desired behavior.